# Mouth-style whistles, i.e. whistles using flexible materials

Tags: materials, airflow

I'm wondering if there is much literature around whistling, i.e. human-mouth style whistling.  Either using your lips or your fingers.

To make my query less vague: say I wanted to create a rubber football with a tube through the axis of rotation (i.e. the axis refers to when the football is thrown in a spiral).  How should one shape the tube, and how fast would one need to throw the football, to make it whistle comparably to a human?  Do we know roughly how much additional drag the whistle will put on the football, when compared to a traditional football shape?  I imagine the material properties of the rubber will matter.  The rubber I will be using will be about the consistency of a rubber o-ring.

I've done a little searching on this topic but I am not certain what keywords are relevant, as there is an enormous literature on whistles, mostly not of the type I am asking about here.

Comment: Why would you use a human mouth and not some other model, like say, a woodwind?

Comment: This is too vague at present: do you want it to sound like some particular "human" whistle?  Are you trying to figure out the best shape (unlikely to be human mouth) to produce sound at relatively low speeds, since you can't throw a football very fast?  and so on.